# Untar specific files using lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, boto3, tar

I'm using a `lambda` function to `untar` files. The `lambda` is supposed to `untar` files and once it's done it moves the package to an archive folder.

Code below

```
def untar_file(zip_key,source_bucket,source_path,file):
 zip_obj = s3_resource.Object(bucket_name=source_bucket,key=zip_key)  
 buffer = BytesIO(zip_obj.get()["Body"].read())
 with tarfile.open(fileobj=buffer, mode=('r:gz')) as z:
     for filename in z.getmembers():
         s3_resource.meta.client.upload_fileobj(
         z.extractfile(filename),
         Bucket=source_bucket,
         Key=source_path+f'/{d1}/{filename}.csv'
         )
 copy_objects (zip_key,source_bucket,source_path,file)
```

I want to only `untar` specific files in the package. Can I specify which file to not `untar`? Just to avoid the lambda timeout

Comment: So your lambda already takes 15 minutes to execute?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out with a simple if statement.

```
zip_obj = s3_resource.Object(bucket_name=source_bucket, key=zip_key)  
buffer = BytesIO(zip_obj.get()["Body"].read())
with tarfile.open(fileobj=buffer, mode=('r:gz')) as z:
    for filename in z.getmembers():
        if any(word not in str(filename) for word in ['text']):
            print(filename)
            s3_resource.meta.client.upload_fileobj(
            z.extractfile(filename),
            Bucket=source_bucket,
            Key=source_path+f'/{d1}/{filename}.csv'
            )
            print ('uploaded')
```